# How do I disable the signature when replying to specific email address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-signature, jira

At work, I use Outlook to add a signature to all my emails.  However, when responding to a JIRA notification, my signature gets added and ends up in the JIRA comment that gets created.

Is there a way I can prevent my signature from making its way into the JIRA comments and cluttering it up?  For example, could I tell Outlook to only include my signature when not writing an email to [address]?

Comment: Which email handler are you using in JIRA?

Comment: @PatrickR. Unfortunately, as a user, I am not sure how to answer that question.  All I know is that the email comes from my organization's domain (`aerojira_request@<myorg>.com`), and is formatted with an Atlassian watermark, with this text at the bottom: `This message was sent by Atlassian JIRA...`

Comment: okay, so we have no chance to use jira to get rid of the signature? I'll try and look into outlooks features later.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook does not support advanced rules when it comes to inserting signatures. The only thing I can suggest is to not automatically include your signature when replying to emails. To can set this in the "Signatures and Stationary" window.

In Outlook 2016, you can find that window by creating a new email, then clicking "Signature" in the ribbon, and then "Signatures" again in the small menu.

More complete instructions, including instructions for other versions of Outlook can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2)